# Импорт данных из Excel в DataGrid wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, excel, datagrid

Здравствуйте, подскажите как из Excel импортировать данные в таблицу DataGrid WPF. Заранее благодарен.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Если вид таблицы заранее известен, то удобно создать свой тип данных. Дальше считать из файла как из любого другого.

Comment: Ваша задача по сути состоит из двух - загрузить данные из Excel-файла и отобразить данные в DataGrid. Какая из этих задач у вас не получается? Если обе - стоит оформить их отдельными вопросами

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, действительно у меня получается две задачи.

Comment: с какой из них возникла проблема?

Comment: Здравствуйте, вообще возникает проблема загрузить именно excel в таблицу datagrid wpf, я в этом как раз не разбираюсь. Или по крайней мере что нашёл, так это именно как загрузить excel в форму, но без участия таблицы datagrid.

Comment: @Евгений, отредактируйте вопрос. Вы загрузили данные из Excel в приложение? Значит с этим у вас проблем нет, это лишняя информация, удалите ее из вопроса. Оставьте только описание структуры, в которой вы храните данные и описание того, как вы хотите эти данные вывести. Ну если, конечно, вы хотите, чтобы вам реально помогли. На данный момент вопрос выглядит слишком общим и вряд ли кто-то на него ответит.

Comment: Спасибо, сейчас попробую более корректно записать вопрос.

Comment: понятнее, к сожалению, не стало

Comment: Мыслей не нахожу. По себе думаю что правильно, а оказывается, что всё осталось в вопросе как есть.

Comment: @Евгений, вы данные из Excel загрузили? Куда загрузили? В массив или в какую-то другую коллекцию или структуру?

Comment: Здравствуйте, да загрузить получилось именно в сам DataGrid, а вот в нужные колонки DataGrid не получается.

Comment: обновите вопрос дополнив его нужной информацией

Comment: Понятно спасибо.

Comment: Прошу прощения, в общем у меня и Excel загрузить не получилось, вроде бы как и пытался всё сделать, можно сказать списал его с другой программы, но всё это кавардаком и кучей-малой. Я понял что мне надо сперва загрузить сам Excel на форму?

Comment: Не сабботируйте вопрос, на него уже ответили в том виде, в котором он был

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вообще такие вопросы нужно закрывать как слишком общие, всеми моими уговорами вы так и не разбили задачу на части и не написали, что конкретно в каждой маленькой части задачи у вас не получается. Я рискну вам ответить и расписать как разбить задачу на части и реализовать каждую часть.

Итак, для начала махом задача делится на две поменьше:

1. Чтение данных из Excel
2. Отображение данных в GUI

## 1. Чтение данных из Excel

Для удобства и ускорения отладки этой части проще сначала создать консольный проект, а не WPF. Именно так я и поступлю.

Первым делом вам необходимо создать модельные классы, экземпляры которых вы будете создавать на основе данных с листа Excel-книги. Я предположу, что у вас одна строка в таблице представляет собой один некий объект (если это не так - вы должны создать другие классы и структуры данных, более подходящие по смыслу):

```
public class Metric
{
    public int Alpha { get; set; }
    public int Beta { get; set; }
    public int Gamma { get; set; }
    public int Delta { get; set; }
}
```

Далее необходимо создать метод, который загрузит данные из Excel и вернет коллекцию экземпляров `Metric`. Нам нужен инструмент, для работы с Excel, я надеюсь, что вы используете более новый xlsx-формат книг, поэтому опишу как можно работать с ним. Я подключил из NuGet пакет [`ClosedXml`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/ClosedXML) (документация и примеры к нему лежат где-то [здесь](https://github.com/ClosedXML/ClosedXML)) и написал такой метод:

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using System.Collections.Generic;

...

static IEnumerable<Metric> EnumerateMetrics(string xlsxpath)
{
    // Открываем книгу
    using (var workbook = new XLWorkbook(xlsxpath))
    // Берем в ней первый лист
    using (var worksheet = workbook.Worksheets.Worksheet(1))
    {
        // Перебираем диапазон нужных строк
        for (int row = 2; row <= 3; ++row)
        {
            // По каждой строке формируем объект
            var metric = new Metric
            {
                Alpha = worksheet.Cell(row, 1).GetValue<int>(),
                Beta = worksheet.Cell(row, 2).GetValue<int>(),
                Gamma = worksheet.Cell(row, 3).GetValue<int>(),
                Delta = worksheet.Cell(row, 4).GetValue<int>(),
            };
            // И возвращаем его
            yield return metric;
        }
    }
}
```

Возможно вам потребуется помимо пути к файлу передавать в метод `EnumerateMetrics` также номер листа и координаты ячеек из которых нужно загрузить данные, я пока это всё "захардкодил".

Отлично, тестируем метод:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var metrics = EnumerateMetrics("Data.xlsx");
    foreach (var m in metrics)
        Console.WriteLine("Альфа: {0}; Бета: {1}; Гамма: {2}; Дельта: {3}",
            m.Alpha, m.Beta, m.Gamma, m.Delta);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Ура! Эта часть работает нормально!

## 2. Отображение данных в GUI

Теперь можно наконец создать WPF проект и разметить главное окно. Я вас прошу, не нужно "рисовать контролы мышкой", пишите разметку вручную, от этого она будет лаконичнее, гибче, да и вам это пойдет на пользу - быстрее поймете смысл всего этого. Итак, нам нужен `Grid` с двумя колонками, в первую мы поместим `DataGrid`, а во вторую `Button`. Я не буду вам сейчас "забивать голову" MVVM и прочим, поэтому просто зададим контролам имена в разметке и подпишемся на событие клика по кнопке:

```
<Grid Margin="5">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <DataGrid Name="MetricsDataGrid" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>

    <Button Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Top"
            Padding="10,5" Click="Button_Click">
        <TextBlock TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap"
                   Text="Загрузить таблицу"/>
    </Button>
</Grid>
```

Вроде хорошо выглядит.

Теперь из прошлого проекта копируем в этот наш класс `Metric` и метод `EnumerateMetrics`, но, так как он не может существовать сам по себе, давайте создадим класс, например `XlsxHelper` и поместим этот метод в него и сделаем его публичным. Ну и не забудьте, конечно, подключить пакет ClosedXml.

Остается только воспользоваться ранее написанным кодом в обработчике клика по кнопке:

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var metrics = XlsxHelper.EnumerateMetrics("Data.xlsx").ToList();
    MetricsDataGrid.ItemsSource = metrics;
}
```

Ну и, чтобы колонки в DataGrid выглядели симпатичнее, отключим автогенерацию и создадим их вручную:

```
<DataGrid Name="MetricsDataGrid" Margin="0,0,5,0"
          AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Альфа" Binding="{Binding Alpha}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Бета" Binding="{Binding Beta}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Гамма" Binding="{Binding Gamma}"/>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Дельта" Binding="{Binding Delta}"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

[image: скрин]

Comment: Спасибо большое, сейчас буду пробовать, я прошу прощения, я редактировал мною написанное сообщение, но видимо не сохранил редактирование и вот сам вижу, что всё мною написанное осталось в прежнем виде.

Comment: Спасибо вам огромное, очень долго мучился но всё-таки достиг результата, с консольным приложением разобрался в раз, а вот с wpf не мог найти опечатку долго, сутки ушли в лёт. В общем я поражаюсь сколько надо усилий и понять рациональную логику в программировании, вот допустим, что мне бы данный код при моём понятии выдался бы где-нибудь через три четыре месяца и то с многими ошибками. Спасибо вам огромное!!!!!!

Comment: @Евгений, пожалуйста, рад помочь. Годик тренировок и вы сможете писать такой код без особых проблем. Если ваш вопрос решен, отметьте ответ галочкой (она слева под кнопками для голосования).