# Найти и обернуть ссылки в тексте

Tags: c#

Делаю чат на C#. Встал вопрос подсветки ссылок в чате.

Нужна функция куда можно передать String (который имеет множество ссылок вида
`ru.stackoverflow.com`) и на выходе получить текст с ссылками в вида

`<a href="ru.stackoverflow.com">ru.stackoverflow.com</a>`

Т.е. нужна возможность подсвечивать ссылки, а не выдирать Url как в подобных примерах.

Прототип функции, которую надо сделать.

```
String ParsingLink(String text)
{
    //.....
    return text;
}
```

Кто может поделиться работающим примером?

Желательно использовать Regex.

Comment: У вас на входе HTML или что? Почему скобки квадратные?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как распарсить HTML в .NET?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/420354/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d1%81%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-html-%d0%b2-net)

Comment: В чем конкретно проблема тогда? Куда вы выводите текст? И при чем тут `Regex`? Каким образом он относится к "посветке" и вообще к GUI?

Comment: Андрей NOP, зачем удаляешь свои записи? вдруг у кого то возникнут такие же вопросы. ps Просьба задачу читать внимательно, а не задавать тысячу вопросов не по теме.

Comment: Я ничего не удалял. Ваш вопрос плох, он содержит в себе несколько вопросов, которые между собой вообще никак не пересекаются: во-первых, вам надо как-то распарсить текст и вычленить из него все ссылки; во-вторых, вам это нужно вывести в GUI. Вы можете разделить свой вопрос на части и если обе они вам не поддаются - задайте их отдельными вопросами.

Comment: Андрей NOP, Вы прекрасно поняли задачу с первого раза. Не надо халтурить.

Comment: Я ее до сих пор не понял. Вот пример подобного вопроса: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/764974/218063 Создайте проект консольного приложения и реализуйте парсинг текста в нем, когда эта часть будет работать как надо - займитесь GUI. На вопрос в текущем виде ответить невозможно, ибо я вообще не представляю, как пересекаются между собой такие вещи как `WPF` и `Regex`

Comment: Только подсвечивать? Или кликабельно должно быть? Я вот не понимаю, о чём вопрос топикстартера, но подозреваю, что вероятнее всего он в эту сторону хочет: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/421031/213987

Comment: A K, мужики, ну я же написал - только функцию. Только подменить stackoverflow.com на <a href>stackoverflow.com</a>

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Накидал на C# используя предыдущий пример на PHP.

```
public String ParsingLink(String source)
{
    Regex regExHttpLinks = new Regex(@"(?<=\()\b(https?://|www\.)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|](?=\))|(?<=(?<wrap>[=~|_#]))\b(https?://|www\.)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|](?=\k<wrap>)|\b(https?://|www\.)[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%?=~_()|!:,.;]*[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#/%=~_()|]", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(source))
        return source;
    var periodReplacement = "[[[replace:period]]]";
    source = Regex.Replace(source, @"(?<=\d)\.(?=\d)", periodReplacement);
    var linkMatches = regExHttpLinks.Matches(source);
    foreach (Match match in linkMatches)
    {
        var m = match.ToString();
        String s = (m.Contains("://")) ? m : "http://" + m;
        source = source.Replace(m,
          String.Format("<a href=\"{0}\" rel=\"nofollow\" title=\"{0}\">{1}</a>",
          s.Replace(".", periodReplacement).ToLower(),
          m.Replace(".", periodReplacement)));
    }
    source = source.Replace(periodReplacement, ".");
    return source;
}
```

Comment: Возможно пригодится, но хотелось бы на C#.

Comment: php на с# не переводятся "влоб". И механизм RegEx+callback не факт что доступен. RegEx реализован весомо иначе. И кодировки по-другому устроены. это ж не `->` на `.` заменить как паскаль-с. В вопросе в тегах обозначено, что с#.

Comment: Согласен с callback погорячился. Переделал под C#. Вроде работает, проверяйте. Добавил обработку от всяких ошибок.

Comment: Только regExHttpLinks можно было бы куда нибудь спрятать в константы. Так как он не будет меняться.

Answer (score 5):

Немного не понятно с подсветкой, но вот функция, которую вы просили

```
 string Find(string inputString)
        {

            Regex regex = new Regex(@"(http|https):\/\/[\w\-_]+(\.[\w\-_]+)+([\w\-\.,@?^=%&amp;:/~\+#]*[\w\-\@?^=%&amp;/~\+#])?");

            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(inputString);
            if (matches.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (Match match in matches)
                    inputString = inputString.Replace(match.Value, "<a href=\""+match.Value+"\">"+new Uri(match.Value).Host+ "</a>");

            }



            return inputString;
        }
```

На входе

```
text1 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787166/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-c#787166 text2 https://vk.com/ text3
```

На выходе

```
text1 <a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/787166/%D0%9F%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3-%D1%81%D1%81%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%B2-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5-c#787166">ru.stackoverflow.com</a> text2 <a href="https://vk.com/">vk.com</a> text3
```

Comment: То, что надо! Спасибо!

Comment: У вас идет завязка на http? Ссылка ru.stackoverflow.com не будет обработана, только https://ru.stackoverflow.com?

Answer (score 3):

Регулярные выражения используются не только для поиска подстроки указанного вида, но и для замены. Эта возможность присутствует в библиотеках всех языков программирования, так что её просто нужно найти.

В C# для замены можно использовать статический метод [`Regex.Replace`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/e7f5w83z(v=vs.110).aspx). Метод получает на вход строку, шаблон поиска, шаблон замены, и возвращает строку, в которое все совпадения заменены указанным образом.

Рассмотрим шаблон `(a|b)(c|d)`. Он совпадает с подстроками `ac`, `ad`, `bc`, `bd`. Когда совпадение будет обнаружено библиотека регулярных выражений создаст подстановку для каждой пары скобок, то есть всего две. Первая подстановка `$1` будет хранить первый совпавший символ, а вторая `$2` — второй.

```
Regex.Replace("fadh", "(a|b)(c|d)", "g$2$1i");
// "fgdaih"
```

Как это работает? Библиотека находит подстроку `ad` внутри `fadh`. Поскольку в шаблоне поиска две пары скобок, библиотека запомнит две подстановки: в `$1` попадёт символ `a`, а в `$2` — символ `d`. Затем вся подстрока целиком будет заменена на шаблон `g$2$1i`, то есть на `gdai`. Всё, что было до найденного совпадения, и то, что будет после него, останется неизменными. Таким образом результатом замены будет строка `fgdaih`.

Для того, чтобы заменить URI на ссылку, надо использовать синтаксис:

```
public string ParsingLink(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text, "(...)", "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
}
```

Здесь вместо `...` нужно указать регулярное выражение, соответствующее URI, например [вот это](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6041965/1051621):

```
public string ParsingLink(string text)
{
    return Regex.Replace(text,
                         @"((http|ftp|https)://([\w_-]+(?:(?:\.[\w_-]+)+))([\w.,@?^=%&:/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&/~+#-])?)",
                         "<a href=\"$1\">$1</a>");
}
```

Comment: Подставил функцию ParsingLink, почему то не работает.

Comment: @hitcode Я всего лишь скопи-пастил регулярное выражение. Вставьте другое, даже в ответе на этот вопрос их привели штук пять.

Comment: просто тогда функцию ParsingLink rename в ParsingExample. :)

Comment: @hitcode Главное, чтобы вы запомнили основной принцип. Остальное можно найти в гугле. Нашёл другой regex, изменил ответ. Проверил. У меня меняет ссылки.

Answer (score 1):

По моему там в одну команду реализуется.

```
Regex.Replace(text, "((http|https|ftp|ftps)://[^\s]+)", "<a href=\"{1}\">{1}</a>");
```

Comment: Хм, а такая ссылка stackoverflow.com не подцепится? Только с http?

Comment: @Anonymous Не подцепится. По современным стандартам, домены могут содержать национальные символы, поэтому `сити.москва` вполне себе домен, может быть даже уже и занятый. С другой стороны, само название метода `Regex.Replace` удовлетворяет правилам именования доменов: два английских слова через точку без пробелов. Так что единственный гарантированный способ определить, URI это или не URI&nbsp;&mdash; указывать *схему*.

Comment: Mark Shevchenko, не знал, интересно.

Comment: Хороший вопрос всплыл. А в чате telegram как работает?